# How to declare an opaque structure pointer interface

Tags: c

I'm trying to architect some C code such that the .c file and private .h file define a rather complex structure, but a public facing header file only requires pointers to that structure type. What I tried was this:

*publicRadio.h*

```
typedef struct _radio Radio;
void radioReceive(Radio *radio, ....);
```

*privateRadio.h*

```
#include <publicRadio.h>
struct _radio {
    ...
    ...
}
```

*radio.c*

```
#include <publicRadio.h>
#include <privateRadio.h>

void radioReceive(Radio *radio, ....)
{
    ...
}
```

When I try to compile this though, I get something like

```
radio.c:91:9: error: parameter 'radio' has just a forward declaration
radio.c:90:6: error: conflicting types for 'radioReceive'
publicRadio.h:29:6: note: previous declaration of 'radioReceive' was here
```

I'm trying to emulate the pattern I've seen in other libraries that have public facing APIs that expose their structures through functions, but hide the gory details. What is the recipe one uses to accomplish that?

Comment: How about including the `publicRadio.h` header *after* the struct declaration?

Comment: Do you have include guards?

Comment: Is the missing semi-colon after the struct declaration a typo?

Comment: Agree with @Matt below. Put structure definition inside our code and leave only abstract struct declaration in header file.

Comment: @TravisGriggs After dabbling with two different compilers, I spotted your errors and have now updated my answer.

Comment: Be careful, all identifiers starting with underscore are reserved in file scope, so you should not use them. If you like such naming conventions, put the underscore at the end rather than at the beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK: The following *does* work on both MSVC and GCC without problems.

**The two important errors were:**

- Missing semi-colon in privateRadio.h
- Including publicRadio.h in radio.c causes double inclusion. It is already included in privateRadio.h

Here is the code I used:

*publicRadio.h*

```
    typedef struct _radio Radio;
    void radioReceive(Radio *radio, ....);
```

*privateRadio.h*

```
    #include "publicRadio.h"

    struct _radio {
        ...
        ...
    };
```

*radio.c*

```
    #include "privateRadio.h"

    void radioReceive(Radio *radio, ....)
    {
        ...
    }
```

*main.c*

```
    #include "publicRadio.h"

    void main()
    {
        Radio* radio = ...;
        radioReceive(radio, ....);
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

This pattern is normally implemented like this:

*radio.h*

```
#ifndef RADIO_H
#define RADIO_H

typedef struct _radio Radio;
void radioReceive(Radio *radio, ....);

#endif
```

*radio.c*

```
#include "radio.h"

struct _radio {
    // _radio struct implementation
};

void radioReceive(Radio *radio, ....) {
    // radioReceive implementation
}
```

*main.c*

```
#include "radio.h"
.... // use Radio, radioReceive, etc.
```

Comment: Nice design but this is somewhat more limited comparing to OP's question. code dealing with internals of `struct _radio` might be spread over several files - and your suggestion doesn't support it.